# Python comparing to different time values to get time delta in minutes

Tags: python, time

I am trying to get get the  time delta i minutes from two different time values.

time1 = 2020-11-28T10:31:12Z
time2 = 2020-11-28T09:10:23.203+0000

Then i will make i condition: if time difference is bigger then x minutes, run code...

Anyone have a solution for that.
I have tried using datetime.datetime.strptime() but cant get them on same format.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using date parser to let it figure out the date format

**Code**

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

def time_difference(time1, time2):
    # Parse strings into datetime objects
    dt1 = parse(time1)
    dt2 = parse(time2)

    # Get timedelta object
    c = dt1 - dt2
    
    # Difference in minutes
    return (c.total_seconds()/60)
```

*Test*

```
time1 = "2020-11-28T10:31:12Z"
time2 = "2020-11-28T09:10:23.203+0000"
print(time_difference(time1, time2))
# Output: 80.81328333333333
```

Answer (score 0):

well assuming you don't need split seconds you could do something like that:

```
time1 = '2020-11-28T10:31:12Z'
time2 = '2020-11-28T09:10:23.203+0000'

import time
import datetime


def get_timestamp(time_str):
    time_splited = time_str.split('T')
    time_str_formatted =  ' '.join([time_splited[0],time_splited[1][:8]])
    return time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(time_str_formatted,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
    

print(get_timestamp(time1))
print(get_timestamp(time2))
```

reformatting both times to the same time format.
then your condition would look like:

```
if abs(get_timestamp(time1) -get_timestamp(time2) ) > x*60:
    do_something(....)
```

Answer (score 0):

The times are not uniform so you will have to make them the same to use strptime. For accuracy I prefer to convert to seconds then you can also at a later stage compare seconds, minutes or hours if you needed to.

```
import datetime

time1 = '2020-11-28T10:31:12Z'
time2 = '2020-11-28T09:10:23.203+0000'

def minutes_diff():   

    #Make the times uniform so you can then use strptime
    date_time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time1[:-1], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
    date_time2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(time2[:-9], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")

    #Convert to seconds for accuracy
    a_timedelta = date_time1 - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    b_timedelta = date_time2 - datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1)
    seconds_time_a = a_timedelta.total_seconds()
    seconds_time_b = b_timedelta.total_seconds()

    #Take one from each other for minutes
    time_in_minutes = (seconds_time_a - seconds_time_b) / 60

    #Then decide what to do with it
    if time_in_minutes < 60: # 1 hour
    
        print('Less than an hours do something')

    else: 
        print('More than an hour do nothing')


minutes_diff()
```

Answer (score 0):

DARRYL, JOHNNY and MARCIN, thanks for your solutions, problem solved!!

Andy